# Error on adding Service Reference due to an amount of service operations

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a service contract with a sufficient amount of operations (~ 40 operations). When I'm trying to add Service Reference from my client project (or even from [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx)) I'm getting an error:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   net.tcp://localhost:12345/DataProvider/mex If this is a Windows (R)
>   Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please
>   check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified
>   address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the
>   MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
>   Error    URI: net.tcp://localhost:12345/DataProvider/mex    Metadata
>   contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'net.tcp://localhost:12345/DataProvider/mex'.    There is an error in
>   the XML document.    The value for the 'type' attribute is invalid -
>   'q2:PersonFilter' is an invalid value for the 'type' attribute.

**The strange behaviour starting here:** when do nothing, but remove **just one** of service operations, everything goes very well - adding of the Service Reference works super good. Of course, I did not tried to remove every method of those ~40, but I've tried ~5. **Another important thing** - I did not remove the method which operates with the `PersonFilter` (the type shown in the error message).

I have no idea, how to fix this. If more information is needed, just let me know.

**UPDATE #1**

So, I've just tried to set mex custom binding to increase defult quotas:

```
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="mexBinding">
      <binaryMessageEncoding>
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                      maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                      maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </binaryMessageEncoding>
      <tcpTransport transferMode="Buffered" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                    maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

and

```
  <service name="MyNamespace.DataService" behaviorConfiguration="myServiceBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:12345/DataProvider/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>

    <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding"
              contract="MyNamespace.IDataService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="mexBinding"
              name="tcp" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
```

but it does not help - the same error is still occuring.

**UPDATE #2**

Using [ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool (Svcutil.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) I've tried to get metadata from 3 following sources:

1. HTTP host
2. TCP host
3. Assembly directly

As for sources 1. and 3. - everything goes fine. I'm able to get metadata and generate client code, but when I call `svcutil` over TCP host I'm getting:

> Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool [Microsoft (R) Windows (R)
>   Communication Foundation, Version 4.0.30319.1] Copyright (c) Microsoft
>   Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Attempting to download metadata from
>   'net.tcp://localhost:12345/DataProvider/mex' using WS-Metadata Exchange.
>   This URL does not support DISCO.
>
> Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool [Microsoft (R) Windows (R)
>   Communication Foundation, Version 4.0.30319.1] Copyright (c) Microsoft
>   Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   net.tcp://localhost:12345/DataProvider/mex
>
> If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you
>   have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing,
>   please refer to the MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.
>
> WS-Metadata Exchange Error
>       URI: net.tcp://localhost:12345/DataProvider/mex
>
> ```
> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://12345/DataProvider/Management/mex'.
>
> There is an error in the XML document.
>
> The value for the 'type' attribute is invalid - 'q2:PersonFilter' is an invalid value for the 'type' attribute.
> ```
>
> If you would like more help, type "svcutil /?"

I'm still have no idea about what is wrong with my wcf service or its configuration.

Comment: Can you post one of the working metadatas along with a non-working one?

Comment: @Frobzig well, to be honest, I can't... I'm able to get metadata from assembly directly, I'm able to get it from the http host, but not from the tcp host.. I'll provide more details in few minutes in my question.

Comment: I've had a similar problem. I don't remember the details, but the problem was that my service was too big. I had to edit visual studio configuration where I've added allowed memory for proxy generation, and the problem was solved.

Comment: @Bogdan0x400 that is pity if the update of the visual studio configuration is needed. I make wcf service for other developers and I can't demand this VS configuration changes to be done.

Comment: So, it seems you have to take a fresh view on your service and divide it into several smaller. It seems that a service with 40 operations looks like "God Object" wich can do everything. Take a look on DDD and idea of bounded contexts.

Comment: @SergioRykov year it might look like the "god object", but it is not. it is a service with bunch of simple CRUD operations. and yes, it should be refactored, but it could not be done until next major release. so, thanks for an advice, but, unfortunatelly, I could not follow it right now :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution a long time ago, but I'm completely forgot to post an answer.

So, I have made some changes in the Visual Studio config file `devenv.exe.config`. I've just added the `system.serviceModel` section as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="GenericBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" name="net.tcp" />
    </client>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="GenericBinding"
                     maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                              maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                              maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                              maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                              maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Now everything works without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally easier to get the service to work with basic http binding first and then change it to net tcp afterwards.

In addition to defining a mex endpoint you need to enable metadata exchange:

```
<behaviors> 
  <serviceBehaviors> 
    <behavior name="myServiceBehavior"> 
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" /> 
        <serviceMetadata /> 
    </behavior> 
   </serviceBehaviors> 
 </behaviors>
```

Without the    `<serviceMetadata />`  element the mex endpoints will not work.